get_class(): Argument #1 ($object) must be of type object, null given
hi i use laravel telescope package
after install in server and use
only in upload file from api or web blade:
get this error:
`exception: "TypeError"
file:"/var/www/html/pickmap/vendor/laravel/telescope/src/Watchers/NotificationWatcher.php"
line: 79
message: 
"get_class(): Argument #1 ($object) must be of type object, null given"
`

i need to fiexd this error
